# Pasre server on AWS EC2 giving 141 error on cloud code

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, parse-platform, parse-server

I am now using the below cloud code to only update "downloads" column on my parse server running on AWS EC2 instance. But I am getting the error code 141(invalid function)

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateDownloads", async (request) => {
    const query = new Parse.Query(request.params.className);
    query.get(request.params.objectId)
    .then((watchFace) => {
        downloads = watchFace.get("downloads")
        watchFace.set("downloads", downloads + 1);
        await watchFace.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
        return "download updated";
    }, (error) => {
      return "something went wrong";
    });
  });
```

I have place my code in `/opt/bitnami/cloud/main.js`.
I even tried adding `“cloud”: “/opt/bitnami/cloud/main.js”` in config.json file but then the parse server gives 503 Service Unavailable error. So I removed it.

Comment: There is no such option but you can try two different approaches: 1) make all of them readonly and create a cloud code function to write this specific column using useMasterKey option 2) make all of them writable and use a beforeSave trigger to validate if only the downloads columns has been changed.

Comment: Hey @DaviMacêdo , thanks for your help. But I use AWS EC2 instance to host my parse server and I have added my cloud function in main.js but now I am getting error code 141. Any help regarding this?

Comment: You need to check your logs. You probably have some error in your main.js file. Also, you need to make sure that you are correctly initializing parse pointing out the cloud code to this main.js file. If you share your current code I can try to help.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Please find the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't add the cloud code `main.js` file to your parse server configuration, parse server will never find your function, and that's why you get the invalid function error.

If you get error when adding the file, you are either adding it in a wrong way (you need to check your parse server initialization code) or the config.json is in wrong format or the cloud code has a problem.

The best way to figure it out is by checking your logs.

At a first glance, a problem that I see (may have others) is the usage of `await` in a function that is not `async`. You are also using a combination of `async` and `then`, which is little strange.

I'd recommend you to change the code to something like:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("updateDownloads", async (request) => {
    const query = new Parse.Query(request.params.className);
    const watchFace  = await query.get(request.params.objectId);
    const downloads = watchFace.get("downloads");
    watchFace.set("downloads", downloads + 1); // You can use inc function to avoid concurrency problem
    await watchFace.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
    return "download updated";    
  });
```

Comment: Man you are the saviour. Everything is working now. I even added the cloud path in config.json and everything is working.

Comment: Also for this to work I will have to update my apps. Can you please tell me how to implement beforeSave just update "downloads" column by +1.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you need but I'd recommend you to give it a try and open a new question in the case you can not figure it out. Anyways, I believe you can use the increment function (https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#counters) and the beforeSave trigger (https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#beforesave) to achieve what you need.

Comment: I would like to add cloud code to update only a specific column and increase its value by 1. I have allowed "update" CLP so I want to check in beforeSave that only "downloads" cloumn is incremented and no other column values can be changed for security porposes.

Comment: You can compare request.object vs request.original data.